# Passing post data from Nginx to Django method

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm having a Django app running on Nginx and Gunicorn, Inside the app i have a `clients.py` file with a method that receives post data from external server and process them, the django url mapped to the method is

```
   url(r'^client/client_request/$', clients.externalclient)
```

The external server won't post data unless it get 200 OK response from my server.
I can log posted data in nginx log but can't catch them to my method in django app, here is my Nginx config

```
server{
      listen 80;
       server_name 00.00.000.000;
       error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
       large_client_header_buffers 4 16k;

    # Tell nginx to ignore favicon
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

   location / {


           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $server_name;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;

         }


  location /assets/ {
            autoindex on;
            alias /var/www/html/dev2_assets/;

     }

  location client/client_post/{
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $server_name;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      keepalive_requests 10;
      keepalive_timeout 75s;
      proxy_redirect http://00.00.000.00/ /client/client_post;
 }

}
```

and here is the django method that receives post request

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def externalclient(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "Request received"
    else:
        print "Method not allowed"
```

Please any one who can see the mistake will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So, indentation is OK? Make next step - replace your `print`s with `return HttpResponse("Request recieved")`

Comment: Yes the Indentation is OK, This is what is see `[22/Dec/2017 02:08:47]"POST /client/client_post/ HTTP/1.0" 302 0`

Comment: That nginx makes no sense to me.  302 is redirection.  You put an explicit one in your nginx to redirect everything at 0.0.0.0.  What are you really trying to do?  You can do the indirect of / inside django where it reads in a lot more straightforward manner.

Answer (score 0):

First: check indentation. I even suggest first check `./manage.py runserver`

Second: if you need correct http response, than `return HttpResponse` instead of `print`

Comment: The indentation is fine in my codes, and  if use  `./manage.py runserver`  to run the app it show `"POST /client/client_post/ HTTP/1.0" 302 0` but it does not show the reponse nor the print text i have put on the method

Comment: Just to be sure: you test your view with `curl -X POST` ?

Comment: I have tried to post this `curl -X csrftoken=370e2a8f-ebae-4aac-b979-ca1eb469ub31 http://00.00.000.000/client/client_post/ -d '{"somekey": "somevalue"}'` Im getting `400 Bad Request` from nginx

Comment: Im still not getting the solution

Comment: I have adjusted curl request to `curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" -X POST http://00.00.000.000:8000/client/client_post` , /manage.py showing `[22/Dec/2017 03:25:45]"POST / HTTP/1.0" 302 0` but it's not showing the return HttResponse

Comment: Excuse me, was out for 2 hours. Peter, forget for some time about nginx and gunicorn, run `./manage.py runserver` and get for `curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/client/client_request` needed result. Did you pass `status=200` to `HttpResponse`?

Comment: No, I have passed a normal text to HttpResponse

Comment: same output `[22/Dec/2017 05:07:49]"POST / HTTP/1.0" 302 0`

Comment: What output should i expect?

Comment: if I return `HttResponse(status=200)` still the method showing `[22/Dec/2017 05:34:57]"POST /client/client_request/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0`